# jquery hide/show submit button based on input field total

Tags: jquery

I have a form that contains about 4 input fields namely: `cash`, `credit_card`, `gift_cert` and `total`. I would like to hide the submit button if the sum of the three fields (`cash, credit_card, gift_cert`) is not equal to the input field(`total`). I think I'm almost there, but my problem lies when I try to decrease the sum, the `addClass` does not work.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFkSv/12/).

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="cash" value="0.00">
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="credit_card" value="0.00">
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="gift_cert" value="0.00">
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="total" value="100">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="test" value="Save">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function () {

    var total = parseFloat($(':input[name="total"]').val(), 10),
        cash = parseFloat($(':input[name="cash"]').val(), 10),
        credit_card = parseFloat($(':input[name="credit_card"]').val(), 10),
        gift_cert = parseFloat($(':input[name="gift_cert"]').val(), 10),
        payment = (cash + credit_card + gift_cert);

    if (payment >= total) {
        $(".test").removeClass("test");
    } else if (payment < total) {
        $(".test").addClass("test");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `show` and `hide` : http://jsfiddle.net/GFkSv/18/

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){

        var total = parseFloat($(':input[name="total"]').val(),10),
            cash = parseFloat($(':input[name="cash"]').val(),10),
            credit_card = parseFloat($(':input[name="credit_card"]').val(),10),
            gift_cert = parseFloat($(':input[name="gift_cert"]').val(),10),
            payment = (cash+credit_card+gift_cert);

        if(payment >= total){
            $('.test').show();
        }else if(payment<total){
            $('.test').hide();
        }       

});
```

**EDIT**

Take into account pre-filled fields after page loading, just fire the `keypress` event afetr `DOM` is ready : http://jsfiddle.net/GFkSv/30/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').trigger('keypress');
});
```

Comment: You shoud also check if the keyboard input is numeric or not

Comment: i have a follow up question, what if the inputs are pre filled that is equal to the total, the submit button does not show.

Comment: @ytse_jam You keep saying you want to the total to equal but you have `>=` is that your intent?

Comment: the sum of (cash, credit_card, gift_cert) should be equal or greater than total for the submit button to show, sorry if i confuse you. thanks everyone for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('keyup change', function(){
        var total = parseFloat($('input[name="total"]').val()),
            cash = parseFloat($('input[name="cash"]').val()),
            credit_card = parseFloat($('input[name="credit_card"]').val()),
            gift_cert = parseFloat($('input[name="gift_cert"]').val()),
            payment = (cash+credit_card+gift_cert);

        $(".test").toggle(payment >= total);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/GFkSv/22/)

Radix is not needed in parseFloat, `on()` is preferred over `bind()`, `:input` should be just `input` these days, and only the name should suffice for you selectors really, and binding to all the keypress events at the same time is just overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you remove ".test" class. Next time you cannot query $(".test") again. Try to use show/hide instead

Answer (score 0):

Or change selector:
http://jsfiddle.net/GFkSv/21/

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){

        var total = parseFloat($(':input[name="total"]').val(),10),
            cash = parseFloat($(':input[name="cash"]').val(),10),
            credit_card = parseFloat($(':input[name="credit_card"]').val(),10),
            gift_cert = parseFloat($(':input[name="gift_cert"]').val(),10),
            payment = (cash+credit_card+gift_cert);

        if(payment >= total){
        $("input[name=submit]").removeClass("test");    
        }else if(payment<total){
        $("input[name=submit]").addClass("test");
        }       

});
```

Answer (score 0):

other way is to summarize all using $.each();

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function () {
    var total = parseFloat($(':input[name="total"]').val(), 10);
    var payment=0;
    $(':input[name="cash"],:input[name="credit_card"],:input[name="gift_cert"]').each(
        function() {
            payment+=parseFloat($(this).val(),10);            
        }
    )
    console.log(payment,total);
    if (payment >= total) {
        $(".test").hide();
    } else if (payment < total) {
        $(".test").show();
    }

});
```